# Tokens expired after changing password

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using [wso2am-2.1.0](/questions/tagged/wso2am-2.1.0) and have an Administrator account which has some access tokens. After changing the password through carbon URL of the administrator account I am not able to use any token.

The error shown:

```
{
   "fault": {
      "code": 900901,
      "message": "Invalid Credentials",
      "description": "Access failure for API: /pinValidation/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have given the correct access token"
   }
}
```

On [wso2](/questions/tagged/wso2) documentation, `900901` means that the token has expired. The tokens have not refreshed or changed after changing the password. Additionally, the expiry for the tokens is set to **UNLIMITED** (meaning that they will never expire)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Very nice statement on their [website](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation) that informs you about the following **"Due to a known issue do not use JDK1.8.0_151 with WSO2 products. Use JDK 1.8.0_144 until JDK 1.8.0_162-ea is released. "**. Does that apply to you as well?

Comment: @ZF007 Unfortunately, no. I am using **JDK1.8.0_101**

Comment: perhaps if you update to 1.8.0_151 your issue is solved? Give it a shot. If not and you run windows try a cold boot (purges data in memory the hardway), del content of temp directories and see if issue persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user changes their password, their tokens are automatically revoked for security reasons.

Comment: So if they are revoked then there should be a way to refresh them from the carbon URL of wso2am, right?

Comment: You have to call /token api and get a new token.